# SQL to remove specific rows from select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ive got a table:

```
UserA UserB UserBB UserAA
```

for example:

```
1 2 2 1
1 3 3 1
2 1 1 2
2 4 4 2
2 5 5 2
5 2 2 5
```

What I want to achieve is to remove rows (duplicates) like to only leave rows as in example:

```
1 2 2 1
1 3 3 1
2 4 4 2
2 5 5 2



2 1 1 2 -> deleted because there is already 1 2 2 1 
5 2 2 5 -> deleted because there is already 2 5 5 2
```

How to write such a query ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you saying two records are equivalent if either A/B are swapped, or AA/BB are swapped, or both A/B and AA/BB are swapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- Find Duplicate Rows

```
SELECT  MAX(ID) as ID, CustName, Pincode FROM #Customers
GROUP BY CustName, Pincode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

-- Delete Duplicate Rows

```
DELETE FROM #Customers
WHERE ID IN 
( SELECT    MAX(ID) FROM #Customers
GROUP BY CustName, Pincode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Taken from MSDN. :
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=DuplicateRows

Let me know if you are unable to figure it out from that code.

This may be a little bit closer to your needs. :

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
WHERE USERA IN ( SELECT MAX(USERA) FROM TABLE
GROUP BY USERA, USERB, USERBB, USERAA HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below also covers situations where UserA and UserB are equal between the two rows but UserAA and UserBB are switched and the reverse. Your question is a bit unclear about what exactly constitutes a duplicate. Hopefully this points you in the right direction at the very least though.

I would turn this into a `SELECT` statement first though and make sure that it is returning the rows that you think should be deleted and only those rows.

```
DELETE T1
FROM
    My_Table T1
INNER JOIN My_Table T2 ON
    (
        T2.UserA = T1.UserA AND
        T2.UserB = T1.UserB AND
        T2.UserAA = T1.UserBB AND
        T2.UserBB = T1.UserAA AND
        T2.UserAA < T2.UserBB
    ) OR
    (
        T2.UserA = T1.UserB AND
        T2.UserB = T1.UserA AND
        T2.UserAA = T1.UserAA AND
        T2.UserBB = T1.UserBB AND
        T2.UserA < T2.UserB
    ) OR
    (
        T2.UserA = T1.UserB AND
        T2.UserB = T1.UserA AND
        T2.UserAA = T1.UserBB AND
        T2.UserBB = T1.UserAA AND
        T2.UserA < T2.UserB
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It was Enough just to add:

Where UserA < UserB